What episode of "To Tell the Truth" did my father appear on?
Sometime around 1975-1976 (I think it's in that range), my father was a guest on To Tell the Truth, a game-show where 2 or 3 guests tried to pretend to be the person who wrote a book or discovered something that got them some recognition but they weren't well known. The celebrities would ask questions and try to figure out which person was the real deal.
It was a controversial episode with an animal handler that was rough with a snake as the initial guest and someone who had written a book about children having equal rights with adults.
The research I've done, this was before tape, they were doing shows by film and no re-runs (er, I think, not positive), and the shows were done daily on weekdays, so there were a couple hundred of shows done every year.   What I've been able to deduce (not 100% sure) is that this was all done on film and the film was nearly all lost, thrown out, recycled for silver . . . what have you. I've tried tivo'ing the To Tell the Truth episodes when they show up on the 500 cable TV channels I have but they tend to be just a handful of recycled shows that often repeat and from the 60s version in B&W not the 70s version and only a handful of shows at that, repeating the same 10 shows over and over.
It would be cool to track down that episode, as I don't have much of my father on video, but I'm guessing it's a super-long shot.   Very few people had VCRs in the 1970s, and we certainly didn't, so recording it didn't even occur to us at the time.   I don't think it occurred to the TV station or anyone that someone might want a copy cause (I think) they didn't use tape and even if they did, most people didn't have a means to play a tape if they got one.
An airdate would be great, but a video would be even better!

I found the video on YouTube. The airdate was Apr 17th, 1974 (incorrectly listed on the Youtube video as May 21, 1974)

Episode 193(2).


My father was part of the 2nd set, impersonating John Holt (incorrectly listed as Jim Hold).
Unfortunately, the video and several other of the old To Tell The Truth videos seem to have been taken down from YouTube. It was fun to see it again, but it appears to no longer be uploaded.

Your link was helpful.   It was Episode 1932.    Whoever uploaded to Youtube apparently got the date wrong.
https://www.ttttontheweb.com/tttt69s5guide.html   Though, to be honest. I don't know how to backtrack from the episode number to the date of the episode.   That website is helpful but a touch unintuitive.

Thanks for that.   The YouTube uploader got #1932 right, and 74 right, but the date wrong.
https://prnt.sc/aEPaSxNtknBs

Great, now we just need to find the darned episode somewhere on the interwebs :-)

A minor note.   April 16th 1974 would be the week.  They did a new show every weekday back then.     Not that a few days matter much.   You can move this to discussion if you like.

So it presumably aired on day 2 of the week, 17/4/'74

The author is John Holt, not Jim Hold. That website is strewn with mistakes.; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Childhood

Annoyingly, episode 193/1 is available on Youtube; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj5zc-ccArs

You might want to send a direct message to GameShowFlashback on Youtube or Facebook. They seem like the obvious choice to get hold of your show; https://www.youtube.com/user/imadkhuri/videos / https://www.facebook.com/groups/481877046054267/
